# How to automate Md2-datepicker using C# selenium?

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, datepicker, automation

We don't have automated date pickers in real life scenarios.

We usually inject date as text into the date fields. but what in case that's not possible. So thought of automating the date picker used in the application.

As most web apps are either migrating to angular latest or developed in angular, I think this will help everyone in helping automate the date picker used. especially md2-datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper class for date selection.

```
 public class DatePickerSelection
    {
        public const string cellSelector = ".md2-calendar-body-cell > .md2-calendar-body-cell-content";

        public static void SetCalenderDate(IWebDriver driver, string EnteredDate)
        {
            string[] dateEntered = EnteredDate.Split("/".ToCharArray()); //to split the dates into day, month and year value
            int month = int.Parse(dateEntered[0]);
            string mon = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);
            int day = int.Parse(dateEntered[1]);
            int year = int.Parse(dateEntered[2]);

            int NoOfClicks = DateTime.Now.Year - year; //to select the year
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.md2-calendar-header-year")).Click();
            for (int i = 0; i < NoOfClicks; i++)
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.md2-calendar-next-button")).Click();
            }
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.zoom='100%'");
            SetMonthAndDate(driver, mon, day);
        }
        public static void SetMonthAndDate(IWebDriver driver, string month, int day)
        {
            SelectMonth(driver, month);
            SelectDay(driver, day.ToString());
        }

        public static void SelectMonth(IWebDriver driver, string mon)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> webElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(cellSelector));
            IWebElement text = webElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.ToLower().Equals(mon.ToLower()));
            text.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(Timing.TimeOut);
        }

        public static void SelectDay(IWebDriver driver, string day)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> webElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(cellSelector));
            IWebElement text = webElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Contains(day));
            text.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(Timing.TimeOut);
        }
    }
```

In the tests, call the SetCalenderDate available in the DatePickerSelection class.

```
string startDate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
SetCalenderDate(driver, startDate);
```